# How to get event name at TestTrack calculated field?

Tags: testtrack

We want to find the event name of an Event item at TestTrack but it options like "Name" or "EventName" and other variants of that are not returning values.

Does anyone know what's the field name?

```
Item.Events.at(0).fieldValue(?????); //It asks for "field name"
```

Thanks in advance,
Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fieldValue function allows you to obtain the value of a field, not the name of a field/event. The list of valid field values is displayed when you press the "Insert Field" button on the Edit Formula dialog. So it is not possible to obtain the event name as part of a calculated custom field value.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to comment that we found that it's not really possible.  
We will probably will use their APIs for what we need.